# Manual occlusion culling with glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, performance, culling

How should I go about doing occlusion culling with `glDrawElements`? I am dealing with voxel-like terrain. I want to avoid drawing the faces that are facing another block. I just don't know how to incorporate this with `glDrawElements`. Should I even use `glDrawElements`?

Comment: `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); glCullFace(GL_BACK);`

Comment: Will it work without having to add implementation with my camera?

Comment: You aren't talking about back-face culling, per your edit. You are talking about occlusion culling.

Comment: Ah, that is a helpful term. Thank you very mush, Josh!